# How to Verify Signature, Loading PUBLIC KEY From CRT file?

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, x509

I reviewed many forums and examples, but none helped me. I need verify signature from any webservice. I have test.crt file with public key for verify.

```
static bool Verify(string text, string signature)
{
  X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(
      HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test-server.cert"));
  RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) cert.PublicKey.Key;

  // Hash the data
  SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
  UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
  byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
  byte[] sign = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
  byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

  return csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), sign);
}
```

But result is always false :(

I have an OpenSSL example:

```
openssl base64 -d -in signature -out signature.bin
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify test-server.pub -signature signature.bin from_gateway
```

Comment: I created a simple app that generates a signature for a text and immediately verifies it. You can check it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1171045/11221877/Program.cs

Comment: So the method above is rather ok. Are you sure that you are using proper certificates for signing and verifying?

Comment: I did the same with web app, so it's not a web thing. How do you pass a signature from web service to your app?

Comment: @drup Are you sure that signing is correct? Because here you are saying you cannot get signature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184890/can-not-get-signature

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, so check your input. E.g. I can see that you seem to use a binary signature for openssl and a base64 encoded one in your C# code. Any wrong character encoding would also do the trick, likely openssl assumes ASCII, you seem to assume 16 bit Unicode (leave it to Microsoft to call an encoding "Unicode", sometimes they can be such idiots).

Comment: My best guess is that you don't want to use `new UnicodeEncoding()` (which I suspect is UTF-16 little-endian, possibly with a BOM). Perhaps you could print the hash and see if it's the value you're looking for?

Comment: Even though the question has 18 votes, I've voted for closing (not a real question) as this question basically requires debugging, which cannot be done without input of the user, drup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the use UnicodeEncoding could be the reason for failures. As demonstrated below the bytes of ASCIIEncoding and UnicodeEncoding are not same for the reason ASCII is a 8bit encoding and in Windows Unicode encoding is 16bit wide. In your other question [Can not get signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184890/can-not-get-signature) you've used the ASCIIEncoding. So assuming signature is computed on the ASCIIEncoding bytes of the text/string and verify using UnicodeEncoding obviously will not match.

```
string text = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine("ASCIIEncoding bytes length: {0}", new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(text).Length);
Console.WriteLine("UnicodeEncoding bytes length: {0}", new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(text).Length);
```

Outputs

```
ASCIIEncoding bytes length: 5
UnicodeEncoding bytes length: 10
```